# I need help resolving CS1503 error "Can not convert from 'string to 'float' " in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a script that will move my object in Unity3D and am encountering a error.

I have googled to see what the problem with my code is and I can not find a solution, most solutions involve adding the new tag in before trying to replace the vector, but I have already done that.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 10.0f;
    public Rigidbody2D player;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }
    public void MovePlayer()
    {
     // This is where the error is being thrown
        player.velocity = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), ("Vertical")) * moveSpeed;
    // This is where the error is being thrown
    }
}
```

I expected this to allow me to control the object with the a and d key in order to move the object left and right, but it throws the error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from string to float

Answer (score 1):

I failed to add the Input.GetAxis before Vertical that line should look like this

```
player.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * moveSpeed;
```